# Merging a data frame in R. Unable to merge due to quotations marks in vector?

Tags: regex, r, merge

I have a data frame, movies_df. I am trying to merge it with another data frame, genres_df, by the title of the movie. I'll use one record, the show "Boy Meets World" to show what's the problem

```
>movies_df[30546]

      votes  rank title                   date    type
30546 29168  8.1 "Boy Meets World" (1993) 1993 TV Show



>genres_df[13126]

      title                  genre_1  genre_2  genre_3  genre_4
13126 Boy Meets World (1993) Comedy   Drama    Family   NA
```

So to merge I tried and got, which both failed:

```
>merge.data.frame(movies_df[30546], genres_df[13126], all.x=TRUE)

  title                    votes rank date type     genre_1  genre_2  genre_3  genre_4
1 "Boy Meets World" (1993) 29168  8.1 1993 TV Show   <NA>    <NA>     <NA>     <NA>

>merge.data.frame(genres_df[13126], movies_df[30546], all.x=TRUE)

  title                  genre_1  genre_2 genre_3  genre_4 votes rank date type
1 Boy Meets World (1993) Comedy   Drama   Family   NA      <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I am almost positive that the problem is that the title fields do not match, because of the quotation marks present in the records of movies_df$title.

So here is how I tried to delete the quotation marks, which all failed:

```
>gsub("\\"", "", movies_df$title[30546])
Error: unexpected string constant in "gsub("\\"", ""

>gsub(""", "", movies_df$title[30546])
Error: unexpected string constant in "gsub(""", ""

>gsub("[[punc:]]", "", movies_df$title[30546])
[1] "\"Boy Meets World\" (1993)"   ##What the heck is this???

>gsub("\\\\", "", movies_df$title[30546])
[1] "\"Boy Meets World\" (1993)"   
##Again, where did the backslashes come from, why can't I delete them???
```

If anyone can help me with a regex to delete those quotation marks or help me merge those two records successfully, then that would be awesome. I read different forums, some saying the quotations don't matter if they are present or not; But I am almost positive they are the reason why I can't merge my two data frames successfully.

More info is that both title vectors in each data frame are of the class 'factor'.

Comment: Can you show the dput output of the the example you showed i.e. `dput(droplevels(movies_df$title[30546]))`  Also in your post `[[punc:]]` should be `[[:punct:]]`

Comment: wow. Yeah can't believe I wrote that wrong... Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dids you try this>?

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", movies_df$title[30546])
```

or

```
gsub('"', "", movies_df$title[30546])
```